# How to logout from another browser after reset the password

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I want to logout from another browser after reset the password.

I use passport.js for user authentication.

So i need a such kind of functionality that if i change my password from one browser then it will automatically logout that user from another browser(When switch to another browser).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

```
function validateToken(token) {
return require("mongoclient").then(function (DB) {
    return DB.query({$collection: "pl.connections", $filter: {token: token}});
}).then(function (data) {
    if (data && data.result && data.result.length > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})
}
```

not a complete implementation but a sample code to validate the token in node with mongo

Add A bit of functionality in your app. maintain a table of token in your db corresponding to users so after a change to password just expire the tokens that are in table for a specific user. Its not just a idea its a working strategy that is adopted by many apps.

Comment: Could you say more detail? or could you show some code example?

Comment: @BlackMamba check the answer for more specification

Answer (score 1):

You can easily archive this using **session Id** which is generated each time a user is authenticated and is unique to a user. But you have to keep track of the **Id**

In this solution am using `express-session`

After a successful authentication `req.session.id` is assigned to the user, it is an alpha-numeric Id(`6QP2t2_ffzkLNPHWNIEuRSXEvNm4lzLb`). You can save this user session Id on account login, Then you can retrieve the user's session from the memory store at any time and destroy it:

```
let session = require('express-session');

const id = req.session.id

sessionStore = express.session.MemoryStore();
sessionStore.get(id, function(err, sess) {
  sess.destroy (function (err) {
   console.log(err, 'if any')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can add `expireAfter` flag to your users table. And when you need to logout somebody just change their `expireAfter` to current time.

If current timestamp is greater than `expireAfter` then you just clear cookies in browser when request comes.
And when login just set expireAfter to 1st January of 2030

```
// something like that
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var user = { ... } // load user from db

  if (user.expireAfter >= new Date().getTime()) {
    res.clearCookie('user_id') // or whatever you have
    var err = new Error('not authorized, please re-login');
    err.status = 403;
    return next(err);
  }

  next();
});

... code code code ...
```

Comment: Your method seems that for every requset, we need `load user from db`? Does it time consuming?

Comment: @BlackMamba yes my method for each request. Simple `SELECT *` will not affect performance very much.

Answer (score -2):

You can create timer at your client side.
use setInterval function.
Send function that will go to server and check if you need logout.

(This Logic is used to check expire sessions, at some systems)

UPDATE:

following to the comment, I notice that I forgot wrotten critical detail:
Of course, server itself need prevent any action when your password is changed. I meant to client side - that you want to logout it.

Comment: Client side logic like this should never be used to control auth because it is not secure.